# ruby, procedures and background processing: strategies to mix it all

Tags: ruby, marshalling, background-process, proc

I'm designing a solution which takes a batch of objects and pipes them into a queue to be handled asynchronously/later. I'm targeting a solution towards delayed_job/resque/sidekiq, where the worker is marshaled/yamled/whatever into a data store and is handled in a separate process.

So, the way I designed it, I have this worker, which takes the object ids, its class and a specific action which have to be run on each of them. Why storing ids and and the class name? These are easily marshable elements (strings, integers), and most data stores have a certain limit for the marshaled data (yes, columns TEXTs, etc.). So far so good.

Now, the culprit: see that action over there? It's not a method identifier. It represents a closure (which takes each object as an argument, and does its magic). This closure is a Proc, and procs are (WHY, LORD, WHY????) not marshable.

So, this messes my plan. I'm devising a strategy towards having a singleton identifier somewhere, and dynamically inserting an auxiliary hidden method, which returns the closure. So, the job gets marshaled with the ids, the class name and this auxiliary method identifier. When the job gets run, what happens is, the action will be run on all the objects, and in the end I'll dynamically remove this method from the singleton instance. For this to work, this identifier has to be unique, and for that I'm using the object_id of the proc closure. So far, so good. Problem is, usually the background queue runs the jobs on a separate process from the one which enqueues them. That means, the dynamically injected methods returning my procs are not available when the job gets run.

So, my problem is subdivised in sub-problems:

1. How to efficiently queue a batch of objects for later processing, where the action to be run on them is not necessarily an existing method?
2. How to work around proc marshalling?
3. How to establish process communication (without using some 3rd party technology message queue, just plain ruby, if possible)

Does anyone know other strategies concerning my problem? Maybe shared memory, inter-process communication, some other? Or maybe a strategy to "marshal" the procs?

Update:

I've devised a solution using DRb, in which this singleton object where I allocate the auxiliary methods get served to external processes as a DRbobject. Have the downside of adding dangerous public API to it. Somebody knows advantages/disadvantages/alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

As for 2. is concerned I had to achieve it with 'singleton recreation'. That is after Marshal.dump / Marshal.load I recreated (not DRY!)

```
def recreate_singleton( obj )
  class << obj
    def method
    end
  end
  return obj
end
```

Comment: yup, did that, and was blocked on the process communication and access to dynamically added methods.